# aligning HorizontalFieldManager to the bottom of the Screen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i am having 4 ButtonField and i want to align all the buttons horizontally. for that i am using HorizontalFieldManager and assigning Field.FIELD_BOTTOM for putting all the button field to the button of the screen. but its not working fine. i don't no what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set [USE_ALL_HEIGHT](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#USE_ALL_HEIGHT) style in manager constructor:

```
class MenuScreen extends MainScreen {        
    public MenuScreen() {
        super(DEFAULT_CLOSE);
        HorizontalFieldManager manager = 
            new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_BOTTOM|USE_ALL_HEIGHT);    
        add(manager);
        manager.add(new ButtonField("1", FIELD_BOTTOM));
        manager.add(new ButtonField("2", FIELD_BOTTOM));
        manager.add(new ButtonField("3", FIELD_BOTTOM));
        manager.add(new ButtonField("4", FIELD_BOTTOM));
    }
}
```

[alt text http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/8776/managerg.jpg](http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/8776/managerg.jpg)

Comment: Hi max...how you can adjust those button width to device width..so that space at right side will not be there

Comment: @iAmitWagh you would need to implement [custom manager with custom layout](http://blackberry-digger.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-create-custom-layout-manager-for.html) and then resize buttonfields in sublayout method to fit screen width.

Comment: Don't forget to put NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL in the MainScreen style.